# Problem using jquery price_format

Tags: jquery, format

I am using plugin jquery-1.4.2.min.js and extension jquery.price_format.js for format price but output result is null

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#price').priceFormat({
    prefix: 'USD$ ',
    centsSeparator: ',',
    thousandsSeparator: '.'
});
</script>
```

input: `<input type="text" name="price" id="price" value=""/>`
ouput: 123456
But result exactly demo is: USD$ 123,456.00
Help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding this code under the document.ready function .

like this.............

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#price').priceFormat({
       prefix: 'USD$ ',
       centsSeparator: ',',
       thousandsSeparator: '.'
    });

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

code demo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Add & Remove list</title>
        <script src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        /*

* Price Format jQuery Plugin
* Created By Eduardo Cuducos cuducos [at] gmail [dot] com
* Currently maintained by Flavio Silveira flavio [at] gmail [dot] com
* Version: 1.5
* Release: 2011-06-27

* original char limit by Flavio Silveira <http://flaviosilveira.com>
* original keydown event attachment by Kaihua Qi
* keydown fixes by Thasmo <http://thasmo.com>
* Clear Prefix on Blur suggest by Ricardo Mendes from PhonoWay
* original allow negative by Cagdas Ucar <http://carsinia.com>
* keypad fixes by Carlos Vinicius <http://www.kvinicius.com.br> and Rayron Victor

*/

(function($) {

    $.fn.priceFormat = function(options) 
    {

        var defaults = 
        {
            prefix: 'US$ ',
            centsSeparator: '.', 
            thousandsSeparator: ',',
            limit: false,
            centsLimit: 2,
            clearPrefix: false,
            allowNegative: false
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() 
        {

            // pre defined options
            var obj = $(this);
            var is_number = /[0-9]/;

            // load the pluggings settings
            var prefix = options.prefix;
            var centsSeparator = options.centsSeparator;
            var thousandsSeparator = options.thousandsSeparator;
            var limit = options.limit;
            var centsLimit = options.centsLimit;
            var clearPrefix = options.clearPrefix;
            var allowNegative = options.allowNegative;

            // skip everything that isn't a number
            // and also skip the left zeroes
            function to_numbers (str) 
            {
                var formatted = '';
                for (var i=0;i<(str.length);i++) 
                {
                    char = str.charAt(i);
                    if (formatted.length==0 && char==0) char = false;

                    if (char && char.match(is_number))
                    {
                        if (limit) 
                        {
                            if (formatted.length < limit) formatted = formatted+char;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            formatted = formatted+char;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return formatted;
            }

            // format to fill with zeros to complete cents chars
            function fill_with_zeroes (str) 
            {
                while (str.length<(centsLimit+1)) str = '0'+str;
                return str;
            }

            // format as price
            function price_format (str) 
            {
                // formatting settings
                var formatted = fill_with_zeroes(to_numbers(str));
                var thousandsFormatted = '';
                var thousandsCount = 0;

                // split integer from cents
                var centsVal = formatted.substr(formatted.length-centsLimit,centsLimit);
                var integerVal = formatted.substr(0,formatted.length-centsLimit);

                // apply cents pontuation
                formatted = integerVal+centsSeparator+centsVal;

                // apply thousands pontuation
                if (thousandsSeparator) 
                {
                    for (var j=integerVal.length;j>0;j--) 
                    {
                        char = integerVal.substr(j-1,1);
                        thousandsCount++;
                        if (thousandsCount%3==0) char = thousandsSeparator+char;
                        thousandsFormatted = char+thousandsFormatted;
                    }
                    if (thousandsFormatted.substr(0,1)==thousandsSeparator) thousandsFormatted = thousandsFormatted.substring(1,thousandsFormatted.length);
                    formatted = thousandsFormatted+centsSeparator+centsVal;
                }

                // if the string contains a dash, it is negative - add it to the begining (except for zero)
                if (allowNegative && str.indexOf('-') != -1 && (integerVal != 0 || centsVal != 0)) formatted = '-' + formatted;

                // apply the prefix
                if (prefix) formatted = prefix+formatted;

                return formatted;
            }

            // filter what user type (only numbers and functional keys)
            function key_check (e) 
            {
                var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
                var typed = String.fromCharCode(code);
                var functional = false;
                var str = obj.val();
                var newValue = price_format(str+typed);

                // allow key numbers, 0 to 9
                if((code >= 48 && code <= 57) || (code >= 96 && code <= 105)) functional = true;

                // check Backspace, Tab, Enter, Delete, and left/right arrows
                if (code ==  8) functional = true;
                if (code ==  9) functional = true;
                if (code == 13) functional = true;
                if (code == 46) functional = true;
                if (code == 37) functional = true;
                if (code == 39) functional = true;
                if (allowNegative && (code == 189 || code == 109)) functional = true; // dash as well

                if (!functional) 
                {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    if (str!=newValue) obj.val(newValue);
                }

            }

            // inster formatted price as a value of an input field
            function price_it () 
            {
                var str = obj.val();
                var price = price_format(str);
                if (str != price) obj.val(price);
            }

            // Add prefix on focus
            function add_prefix()
            {
                var val = obj.val();
                obj.val(prefix + val);
            }

            // Clear prefix on blur if is set to true
            function clear_prefix()
            {
                if($.trim(prefix) != '' && clearPrefix)
                {
                    var array = obj.val().split(prefix); 
                    obj.val(array[1]);
                }
            }

            // bind the actions
            $(this).bind('keydown', key_check);
            $(this).bind('keyup', price_it);

            // Clear Prefix and Add Prefix
            if(clearPrefix)
            {
                $(this).bind('focusout', function()
                { 
                    clear_prefix();
                });

                $(this).bind('focusin', function()
                { 
                    add_prefix();
                });
            }

            // If value has content
            if ($(this).val().length>0)
            {
                price_it();
                clear_prefix();
            }


        });

    };      

})(jQuery);
</script>
    <input id="example6" type="text" value="-123456" name="example6">
    <script>
    $('#example6').priceFormat({
        allowNegative: true
    }); 
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```